# CountRows with loop value from gallery - stored in list

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

I have a column stored in a "list" that has 1, 2, or several codes separated by ","

[image: List]

I want to count the number of records that each of those codes meet + a range of filters

I show each record in a gallery vertical, so in a "label" I place the following formula to evaluate it in each item of the gallery

```
ClearCollect(codesAnomalias; Split(ThisItem.CODE_ANOMALIA; ","));;
ForAll(codesAnomalias;  
            CountRows(
                With(
                {
                    wData:
                    Filter(
                        'BD DATA';
                        codigo_anomalia = Value
                    )
                };
                Filter(
                    AddColumns(
                        wData;  
                        "ChasisNo";
                        Value(Right(chasis;6))
                    );
                    ChasisNo >= ThisItem.CHASIS_INICIO &&
                    ChasisNo <= ThisItem.CHASIS_FIN
                )
                )
          )      
)
```

I think I have a mistake in the first step. What is the Split and ForAll,

Can anyone help me understand what is the error in the iteration and the gallery?